# need a regex for a positive max 2 digits after . floating number

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hi
I need a C# regex for a positive floatin no with maximum 2 digits for decimals. Also the regex should check for letters and alphanumerical chars (not allow  them) and not allow also the input value to be empty (0 characters).
Thanks

Comment: Sorry we won't do your work/homework for you. How about showing us what you've tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: I agree with the @Ahmad and @Alex; that's a pretty straightforward query. Try these resources: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/

Comment: Agreed. Also look at http://regexlib.com and O'Reilly has a good "Regular Expressions Cookbook".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[+]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

This will force it to have either a `+` or nothing at the start, followed by at least 1 number, then optional (decimal followed by 1 or 2 numbers)

For others, yes, I know of `\d`, `:digit:`, using `\.`, etc. I just prefer using [0-9] and [.], it makes them stand out easier for me.

Comment: unfortunately i have tried this with expresso it works, but when I am using a regularExpressionAttribute in C# it does not behave as expected.Basically 4.2345 passes 4. passes 4.1 does not pass.